# How to add static field (not affected by filters) in Power Pivot

Tags: excel, pivot, powerpivot

I have power pivot table with efficiency of different employees. I want to be able to filter values to see on a graph efficiency of only selected employees, but at the same I want to see an average efficiency of all employees including those that are filtered out.

Answer (score 0):

Add a measure to your powerpivot that looks like this:

```
[Static Average Efficiency]:=AVERAGEX(ALL(Table1),Table1[Efficiency])
```